# How to change the date column based on time column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, date, datetime

I have a dataframe which looks like this:

```
ID      Date     Type     Time
1   02.12.2021   Car      12:23
1   02.12.2021   Car      12:25
1   02.12.2021   Car      12:27
2   02.12.2021   Train    23:40
2   02.12.2021   Train    23:56
2   02.12.2021   Train    00:20
2   02.12.2021   Train    00:40
4   02.12.2021   Car      04:20
4   02.12.2021   Car      04:25
4   02.12.2021   Car      04:30
```

I want change the date for those rows which have the same "ID" and "Type". So if the time of next row passes 23:59 and has same ID and Type like the row before, the date should change for the next rows.
It should be something like this:

```
ID      Date     Type     Time
1   02.12.2021   Car      12:23
1   02.12.2021   Car      12:25
1   02.12.2021   Car      12:27
2   02.12.2021   Train    23:40
2   02.12.2021   Train    23:56
2   03.12.2021   Train    00:20
2   03.12.2021   Train    00:40
4   03.12.2021   Car      04:20
4   03.12.2021   Car      04:25
4   03.12.2021   Car      04:30
```

Any help will be appreciated.
Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

Let's try to create a boolean series where the new date starts and that number of days to each Date:

```py
# Ensure Types Are Correct
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format="%d.%m.%Y")
df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time'])


df['Date'] = df['Date'] + \
             df['Time'].diff().dt.days.lt(0).cumsum().astype('timedelta64[D]')

# Fix Formats
df['Date'] = df['Date'].apply(lambda x: x.strftime("%d.%m.%Y"))
df['Time'] = df['Time'].apply(lambda x: x.strftime('%H:%M'))
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   ID        Date   Type   Time
0   1  02.12.2021    Car  12:23
1   1  02.12.2021    Car  12:25
2   1  02.12.2021    Car  12:27
3   2  02.12.2021  Train  23:40
4   2  02.12.2021  Train  23:56
5   2  03.12.2021  Train  00:20
6   2  03.12.2021  Train  00:40
7   4  03.12.2021    Car  04:20
8   4  03.12.2021    Car  04:25
9   4  03.12.2021    Car  04:30
```

---

`df['Time'].diff()` gets the difference between this and the previous Time value as a TimeDelta. If it belongs to the previous day as in 23:56 moves to 00:20, the value of days will be -1. For this reason, a boolean index can be created based on where there are -1s. `df['Time'].diff().dt.days.dt.days.lt(0)`. With this information `cumsum` can be applied to create a series of values that represent grouped days together, starting at 0 and increasing by 1 each time a -1 days is encountered.

```py
print(df['Time'].diff().dt.days.lt(0).cumsum())
```

```
0    0
1    0
2    0
3    0
4    0
5    1
6    1
7    1
8    1
9    1
Name: Time, dtype: int32
```

Then change type to `timedelta64[D]` to add the offset to each date.

```py
print(df['Time'].diff().dt.days.lt(0).cumsum().astype('timedelta64[D]'))
```

```
0   0 days
1   0 days
2   0 days
3   0 days
4   0 days
5   1 days
6   1 days
7   1 days
8   1 days
9   1 days
Name: Time, dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

Comment: I would think it makes more sense if his examples of dates were in the format `"%d.%m.%Y"`. Changing the month when time passes to the next day makes no sense. However the OP might be able to answer if my hunch is correct.

Comment: Thank you!! That makes way more sense and is way easier. I was just looking at the input vs outputs and missed the explanation.

Comment: @HenryEcker the time format is incorrect. When I'm trying to change the type, the date will be added to time columns as well. By the way is the #Fix Format part necessary for the code. I get an error with the last as well. It says , NaTType does not support strftime. Thanks

Comment: The fix format is the part of the code is the part that removes the date portion of `Time` and the time portion of `Date`. NaTType does not support strftime means that there are nulls in your data somewhere. How do you expect to handle those cases?

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is a first step adding the start of trip to each row and then simply compare and add one day:

first get the start date/time

```
df=df.merge(df.groupby(["ID","Type"]).first(),on=["ID","Type"], suffixes=(None,'Start'))
```

then compare and add if applicable:

```
df.loc[(df["Time"]<df["TimeStart"]),"Date"]=df["Date"]+pd.Timedelta(days=1)
```